# Как использовать "use ClassName" во вьювах

Tags: php, laravel

Часто приходится использовать константы классов во view'ах, что подразумевает полное имя класса с нэймспейсом, что приводит к здоровенным нечитабельным условиям.
Вопрос: можно ли во вьюве каким то образом использовать аналог `use \vendor\ClassName`?

Comment: Добавить alias или пробросить име класса в переменную шаблона?

Comment: А можно по подробнее? пример?

Answer (score 0):

Один из способов сделать так, пример из документации:

```
@inject('metrics', 'App\Services\MetricsService')
<div>
    Monthly Revenue: {{ $metrics->monthlyRevenue() }}.
</div>
```

Так же ты можешь вводить переменные которые будут видны во всех Шаблонах:

Например в App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
public function boot(){
    //...что то до этого например создаешь экземпляр класса obj
    \View::share('obj',$obj);
}
```

Comment: А если мне надо получить доступ к константе класса а не к методам объекта?

Comment: @Oleg Shakhov Создай хелпер класс например или сервис контейнер который будет возвращать тебе то, что нужно

Comment: @Oleg Shakhov А вообще, если у тебя класс одних констант, то тебе проще создать файл в конфиге, и брать оттуда `conf('my_settings_file.my_const_name');`

Comment: У меня класс - модель у который есть статусы в виде констант и вот надо проверять - соответствует ли статус модели конкретной константе.

Comment: @Oleg Shakhov  чет я не понял так у тебя если экземпляр класса передается так там к константе и обращайся, ну ли вообще сделай вспомогательную функцию у экземпляра, которая будет тебе делать проверку нужную. И вообще приведи пример четкий, как у тебя есть и что ты хочешь сделать